# Exponential equation in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to recreate the following equation in solidity.

[image]

I know that solidity does not have the concept of floating point numbers so I am trying to use the [ABDKMathQuad](https://github.com/larvalabs/cryptopunks/blob/master/contracts/CryptoPunksMarket.sol) library. Unfortunately I've not had much success *(I've not even been able to multiply two floating point numbers together)*

```
bytes8 a = 0x0000000000018000;  // 1.8
bytes8 b = 0x0000000000024000;  // 2.4
bytes16 a_16 = ABDKMathQuad.fromDouble(a);
bytes16 b_16 = ABDKMathQuad.fromDouble(b);
bytes16 _temp = ABDKMathQuad.mul(a_16, b_16);
bytes8 result = ABDKMathQuad.toDouble(_temp);
```

Even

```
bytes16 a = 0x00000000000000000000000000018000;  // 1.8
bytes16 a = 0x00000000000000000000000000024000;  // 2.4
bytes16 _temp = ABDKMathQuad.mul(a, b);
```

Doesn't seem to yield anything.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using  Avatar
Paul Razvan Berg' brilliant [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math/tree/v1.0.3) library.

```
import "prb-math/contracts/PRBMathSD59x18.sol";

contract SimpleContract {

    using PRBMathSD59x18 for int256;

    function exponential_function(int256 x) public view returns (int256) {
        int256 z = 90000000000000000;      // 0.09
        int256 a = 200000000000000000;     // 0.2
        int256 b = 1080000000000000000;    // 1.08
        int256 c = -10000000000000000000;  // -10
        int256 d = 100000000000000000;     // 0.1
        int256 _x = x * 1000000000000000000;
        int256 outcome = PRBMathSD59x18.mul(a, b.pow(PRBMathSD59x18.mul(z, _x) + c)) + d;
        return outcome;
    }
}
```

*(Though as noted in his repo the `pow` function is about four times more expensive than the one in [ABDKMath64x64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/d8817cb600381319992d7caa038bf4faceb1097f/ABDKMath64x64.md))*